# gitolite on openwrt - ssh not using gitolite

Tags: openwrt, gitolite

I've set up a gitolite installation on OpenWrt-18.06.04 according to this guide:
https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/gitolite

Step 9 of the "actual install" suggests removing the RSA-key from 
/srv/git/.ssh/authorized_keys

If I do so, I cannot connect over shh git@openWRT at all.
If I leave the key in there I can connect, but it results in a normal ssh session, no gitolite (The key of my admin-gitolite user is the same as the openwrt admin rsa key)

```
echo normal access
```

returns

```
normal access
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about openwrt, but gitolite needs its own key; it can't use the same one that you use for normal shell access.

There *are* ways around that, but you need to set them up; see https://gitolite.com/gitolite/sts.html#giving-shell-access-to-gitolite-users for how.

Even so, I'd be wary of doing that to, say, a remote VPS, if that key is my *only* access to the box.  Not that there's any known problem with that method, just playing safe.  However, for a local box (or router) it should be fine.